# Best way to handle keyboard events when losing focus

Tags: javascript, dom, keyboard, focus, alert

My webapp has implemented keyboard shortcuts. For each key, I have a boolean variable whether it is pressed. When some specific shortcut appears, I make some action.

The problem is, that some actions make my document lose focus (e.g. Open dialog, Save dialog or simple alert()) and my webapp has no chance to find out, whether keys were released or not.

Is it possible to keep getting keyboard events even during alert() ? I know I can set all keys to False, when some shortcut appears. Is there something more elegant?

```
if(ctrlDown && mDown) alert("...");
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/fvqhbLa1/1/ The document shows, whether Ctrl, M, B are pressed. But when you press Ctrl and M, there is alert, after closing it document still thinks that Ctrl and M are pressed. Now you can press Ctrl and it fires alert() without pressing M.

Answer (score 0):

You could reset all pressed key when you send an alert, because most of the users won't press Ctrl while the alert box is shown.

You could also check whether shift, ctrl, and alt keys are down by using the 'e.shiftKey', 'e.ctrlKey' and 'e.altKey' properties.

```
alert("Ctrl + M pressed!");
ctrlDown = bDown = mDown = false;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fvqhbLa1/3/

Comment: I know about this "solution". But I have about 100 shortcuts and 100 actions, e.g. Ctrl+Space is action A, Ctrl+Space+Alt is action B (A and B keep focus), I need to switch between A and B just by pressing and releasing Alt (while holding Ctrl and Space). My code would get 2x longer, if I do it as you say.

Comment: Is there any way to get pressed keys without keyboard event? Or some other solution?